# Perforce: Failed to import project from release stream which is now deleted in dev stream

Tags: import, stream, perforce, release, p4v

I have SolutionA which has imports from SolutionB. Both are on release streams. However, I deleted one project in SolutionB's dev stream, assuming that it doesnot affect the release stream. But, even though it didn't affect SolutionB's release stream, that specific project that I deleted (in SolutionB's dev stream) is removed from SolutionA's release stream. Is there way I could import the project from SolutionB's release stream to SolutionA's release stream?

Update: here is the specs for the SolutionA stream (Project1 is deleted from the SolutionB's Dev stream followed by SolutionB's.Mainline, but is still there is Solution.Release.1.0.0 release stream)
[image]
and here is the stream spec for SolutionB's release stream
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you include the stream specs in the question?

Comment: The actual stream specs (most importantly the `Paths` that define the files contained in each stream and where they come from), not just the stream graph.

Comment: @Samwise got it. just updated. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Gonna need to see the `SolutionB.Release` stream spec too (to be able to understand the dependency between that and the dev stream you deleted the files from).

Comment: @Samwise added the stream spec for SolutionB. The project1 was initially created in SolutionB, but was deleted later on dev followed by mainline.

Comment: I don't think that your description of events is accurate.  What do you see if you run `p4 files //depot/SolutionB.Release.1.0.0/Components/SolutionB.Project1/...`?

Comment: According to your stream spec, that's where the files for the project should be -- if they're present (and not deleted), you should see them in SolutionA as well.

Comment: @Samwise yes, i see those files when i run p4 files //depot/SolutionB.Release.1.0.0/Components/SolutionB.Project1/... but the weird part is, SolutionA.Release.1.0 was working until the project got deleted in SolutionB.Dev. We haven't made any change to the release stream, and it suddenly didn't work. Any ideas how we should debug this?

Comment: Use `p4 where` to see where all the files should be coming from, and `p4 files` to see the current state of those files in the depot.  StackOverflow is not a good place to have a back-and-forth remote debugging session; if you post on forums.perforce.com I can try to help there.

Comment: i initially wanted to post in the forum. but the site doesn't respond when i sign-up.